# How to hide fields on the view part of the Grails CRUD dynamic scaffolding?

Tags: grails

I was wondering if there is another way of making a certain field of a domain to not appear in the views pages of the dynamic scaffolding capability of Grails?

I can execute the `generate-all` command on the domain and edit the view myself but I was just wondering if there is a way for me to still take advantage of the dynamic scaffolding capability.

I just want to not show the password field on the `show` and `edit` views of my user domain.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Scaffolding shouldn't really be used beyond learning and quick demos anyway.

Comment: If masking the value (instead of hiding the field completely) would be enough, there is a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40774872/1004651

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would disagree with Gregg's comment above. Scaffolding is very helpful in reducing unnecessary code.

Add a constraint called `display:false` to that property in your domain class, i.e,

```
static constraints { 
   password display: false
}
```

This will hide the property for you when scaffolding.

Docs: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

Comment: hi @tomas, thanks for the info. I did not know that there is a display option. thanks for that, but I did the manual way of hiding the password field by generating the static code then taking out the password field from the show and list views. I tried applying the display attribute on my domain but it also hid the field on the create view. anyway, thanks again

Comment: you can customize the render editor template after calling grails install-templates to do this based on the view name. But I guess it might be more trouble than what it is worth.