# Hide relationship field from view via domain class / scaffolding

Tags: grails, crud, dsl

I need to hide a relationship field from view that is generated by scaffolding in Grails.

I found similar question and answer: [is there a way to hide fields on the view part of the grails crud dynamic scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684645/is-there-a-way-to-hide-fields-on-the-view-part-of-the-grails-crud-dynamic-scaffo)

However above answer doesn't seem to help when applying to relationship field. Here is an example:

```
static hasMany = [car:Car]

static constraints = {
    car (display: false)
}
```

Please can anyone tell me how to hide a relationship field via Domain class definition?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Grails ? Any missing code ? Did you generate and customize any GSP view ?

Comment: I am using 2.1.0. No missing code, no generated GSP - everything is via scaffolding.